# Using __builtin_ia32_shufps to shift a vector by 32 bits?

Tags: c, vectorization, simd, shift

This is the prototype for the function:

```
v4si __builtin_ia32_shufps (v4si, v4si, int)
```

On some websites I found they had but hex in the int field, and it looked liked it separated high and low bits, but what I want is a logical 32 bit shift.

```
X3 X2 X1 X0 shifted by 32 bits to get X2 X1 X0 0
```

Another example using 2 v4si vectors:

```
X7 X6 X5 X4 | X3 X2 X1 X0, where each X is a 32 bit and what I want for a shift is the 
same a logical shift, but with each vector element. So:
X7 X6 X5 X4 | X3 X2 X1 X0 << 2 = X5 X4 X3 X2 | X1 X0  0  0
```

Is shufps the right command to do this?

Comment: I think you mean "bits" not "bytes".

Comment: Correct I did mean bits, v4sf is a 128 bit vector, split into logical 4 32 bit vectors.  I think*

Comment: Are you sure you want to bitshift floating point numbers?  Because the `v4sf` type is for 4 32bit floating point numbers.

Comment: Yes, but if it makes it simpler to think about as ints, then I can redefine the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your example with two vectors I think what you're probably looking for is [_mm_alignr_epi8 (PALIGNR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514041.aspx). This works for any shift of a pair of vectors by an arbitrary number of *bytes*, so you would need to multiply the shift parameter by `sizeof(int)`, e.g.

```
v = _mm_alignr_epi8(v0, v1, 2 * sizeof(int));
```

Note that this instruction is only available in SSSE3 and later, which means pretty much any Intel CPU since ~ 2005.